# can i make a variable that is set to the width of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am developing a website for my own company. i came to a problem, when you make your page smaller some div's overstack eachother. i was wondering if you can make a variable that is set to the width of the page so you can change your css whit javascript when needed using that variable.

i have tried the following script in css without succes

```
display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
```

[when the page becomes smaller than 1840px. the 4 pictures on the right will overlap the text box on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw6yk.jpg)

now is my question how to make the text block shift up when the page gets below 1840px

Comment: this is called viewport unit https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

Comment: thnx! this was indeed the solution that i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to begin looking into **[Responsive Web Design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/)**, which says that pages should be comprised of:

- **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** (that allow "conditional" styling)
- Flexible Layouts (i.e. **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)** or **[CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)**)
- Responsive Media (using size units that allow for media to
  grow/shrink as needed)

Your particular issue could be addressed with:

- Media Queries (when the viewport size is `x`, apply style `y`)
- Responsive Media (set image sizes to relative units like `%`, `vh`,
  `vw`)